# Solve $2tx'(t)-x(t)=\ln x'(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $2tx'(t)-x(t)=\ln \left[x'(t)\right]$

That would be an easy Clairaut's equation if $tx'(t)$ wasn't multiplied by $2$. But unfortunately it is, and I have no idea what to do here.

Comment: Is $x$ a function of $t$?

Comment: Yes, $x$ is a function of $t$

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*t*x%27+-+x+%3D+ln%28x%27%29) spits out an implicit solution in terms of the Lambert-W function.

Comment: @Lugi From a notational point of view, I would replace $x'$ with either $x'(t)$ or with $\dot x$. That way it's completely unambiguous which variable your derivative is with respect to.

Answer (score 0):

Effectively, solving for $x'$ $$2tx'-x=\ln (x')$$ leads to $$x'=-\frac{W\left(-2 t e^{-x}\right)}{2 t}$$ which explains  the implicit solution in terms of the Lambert function as already mentionned by JimmyK4542 $$W\left(-2 t e^{-x}\right)-\log \left(2+W\left(-2 t
   e^{-x}\right)\right)+x=C$$ In fact, the solution of $$atx'-x=\ln( x')$$ is given by $$W\left(-a t e^{-x}\right)+(1-a) \log \left(a+W\left(-a t
   e^{-x}\right)\right)+x=C$$ which, for $a=1$, simplifies to $$x=e^{-C} t+C$$ Now, how to integrate for the general case $a\neq 1$ ? This is a big question.